# delete record from gridview but not from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete record from grid but not from Database.

I want to set database field ISDeleted 1 when data deleted from gridview but don't want to delete record from db.

My code delete records from both gridview and db.

Where to change in my code-

```
 string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand command;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblAdd.Visible = false;
    Label1.Visible = false;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            fillLanguageGrid();
        }
}

public void fillLanguageGrid()
    {   
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chk");
        if (chkdelete.Checked)
        {
            string name= Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["Name"].ToString());
           // command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            deleteRecordByName(name);
        }
    }
    fillLanguageGrid();
}

public void deleteRecordByName(string Name)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[hrm_Langauges]", sqlConnection))
    {
        //  define this to be a stored procedure
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
        // define the parameter and set its value
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = Name;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 1;
        command.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Delete";
        //open connection, execute DELETE query, close connection
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to add a column in your respective database table whether to show that record or not.For Ex: add column like **Visible int**.

Assume if

Visible =1 --> Show that record in gridview

Visible =0 --> Hide that record in gridview

By default make **Visible =1** so all records are shown in gridview(write the query like  *Select ......Where Visible =1*).when you try to delete record use **update** **query** that need to update **Visible** column **1 to 0**.So your gridview only shows records where visible =1 .That particular deleted record is not shown in your gridview because its **Visible** column is 0.Try this..